# Meta-analysis of single arm study to compare different interventions

Tags: meta-analysis

I have a collected data regarding single arm studies treating certain disease with either technique A or technique B with no direct comparison between the techniques in each of the studies. for example:

study    technique
1    ->      A
2     ->     A
3      ->    B
4       ->   B

Is it possible to do meta analysis and compare the techniques A vs B by comparing the studies 1&2 vs 3&4 thought no direct comparison was done between A and B in each independent study ? and if I sum the study population and its success rate\complications in study 1&2 and compare it to the sum study sample of study 3&4, would it be acceptable ? does this considered a type of meta-analysis?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can pool all the studies that report on intervention A separately and all the studies that report on intervention B separately. I would not recommend trying to make anything more than an observation of the differences between the two pooled estimates. Even then, these studies are at high risk of bias (almost always), and could be using different populations, intervention characteristics, confounders, etc. This is all for hypothesis generation rather than confirming a hypothesis.